# Global Navigation drop down menu has 2 different lengths

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, metadata, global-navigation

I have drop down menu with a parentage and it shows up really nicely from the main page. But if i try to access the same menu while on a sub-page it looks ugly and the width of the drop down menu is different.

How can I fix this please help ?

[image]

Comment: anybody............................?